# javascript iterating and remapping

Tags: javascript, mapping

I have a data set that looks like this:

```js
const data = [["customer1",29349,3654],["customer2",29349,3654],["customer3",15178,130]
```

I need to transform the data into this using a map.

```js
series: [{
    category: 'Resolved before conciliation',
    data: [29349, 29349, 15178]
}, {
    category: 'Conciliation successful',
    data: [3654, 29349, 130]
}]
```

I've tried the following which gets me my first category but I can't seem to work out how to get my second category into my series within the same map.

```js
const series = [{
    name: 'Resolved before conciliation',
    data: data.map(([...data]) => (data[1]))
}]

console.log(JSON.stringify(series))
```

Output:

```js
[{"name":"Resolved before conciliation","data":[29349,29349,15178]}]
```

Comment: where do you get the missing parts from?

Comment: You are grouping stuff, I wouldn't use `map` for this. `reduce` is much better.

Comment: Its the second set of values in the data variable. This needs to map to the "Conciliation successful" category.

Comment: It might be helpful to show that second set of values.

Comment: Its the 3654, 3654, 130 in my example data variable.

Comment: How does `3654, 3654, 130` turn into ''Resolved before conciliation''

Comment: I need to map these into the other "Conciliation successful" category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping with reduce:

```js
const data = [["customer1",29349,3654],["customer2",29349,3654],["customer3",15178,130]];

let reduced = data.reduce((results, arr) => {
   results[0].data.push(arr[1]);
   results[1].data.push(arr[2]);
   return results;
}, [{ category: 'Resolved before conciliation', data : [] }, { category: 'Conciliation successful', data : [] }]);

console.log(reduced);
```

Comment: Arh OK, I was using completely the wrong function. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could push the values to the array with the same index.

```js
const
    data = [["customer1", 29349, 3654], ["customer2", 29349, 3654], ["customer3", 15178, 130]],
    result = { series: [{ category: 'Resolved before conciliation', data: [] }, { category: 'Conciliation successful', data: [] }] };

data.forEach(a => a.slice(1).forEach((b, i) => result.series[i].data.push(b)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks - Im going to experiment with both answers here. However, it looks like `reduce` is what I need